# Block specific websites when connected to certain wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless, permissions, dns

I'm wondering, is there a way to configure Ubuntu to block access to specific websites when I'm connected to a particular network.

I'm not in control of the WiFi router, so I can't block it at a router level. Is there a way to do this, maybe with local DNS, or firewall configuration?

My main interest in doing this is in stopping my habit of using social networks at school, so I don't need the blocking to be super secure (though I don't want to do it in a way that opens me up to new threats).

Comment: You can try implementing Squid, or block the DNS queries with unbound for example.

Comment: Look this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943381/how-to-block-website-using-squid-server